# How does one measure an arbitrary observable $\Omega (X,P)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

In classical mechanics, there exist experiments to measure any observable $\omega (x,p)$. This is because, once we measure $x$ and $p$ simultaneously, we can by extension say that we have also measured $\omega (x,p)$. $\omega (x,p)$ can be any arbitrary function of $x$ and $p$. Any experiment that measures $x$ and $p$ simultaneously also measures every possible observable.

In quantum mechanics, do there exist experiments to measure any arbitrary Hermitian operator cooked up from $X$ and $P$?

Comment: What are the criteria for an experiment to "exist"? How you actually measure something *in practice* for a quantum mechanical system highly depends on the actual system, but you didn't specify any particular system here.

Comment: The very word "observable" means it is a variable that one observes. Then one tries to find the function describing the observable. In classical gravity first came the orbits of the planets and then the measurement of the velocities.  One does not generate fictional observables.  The same is true for quantum mechanics, imo, with different postulates than classical mechanics, but still  definitely something to be observed/measured